# No push notification on iOS with React-native-firebase. Invalid team id key id and APNs auth key combination when try to send from console

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Notifications stopped working after I did 2 things:

1) created second project on firebase

2) updated react-native-firebase from 3.3.x to 4.3.x

Answer (score 2):

I've wasted 2 hours debugging this and want to save time for other people.

The issue was that I didn't simply upload APNs Authentication Key for a new project and this step is hard to find but it should be **the first thing** you do if you face this problem.

Here is a link how to create APN auth key and other certificates for Push notifications https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

To upload APN auth key go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR-PROJECT -> go to overview -> select ios app -> go to Cloud messaging